# Fluid simulation into keyframes?

Tags: animation, modifiers, physics, keyframes, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to play fluid simulation in reverse in a dope sheet. I've baked the simulation cache, but the option to bake it into key frames does not exist, it does only for rigid body simulations. I've tried using stop motion OBJ add-on with the same  results. I need it to be in actual scene dope sheet as it plays along other complicated animations (imagine T2 scene where T1000 unmelts from the floor and attacks the victim). Any solution or any workaround short of writing own scripts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a script to re-write the name of the files in the cache folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Alembic export and import it back. It will import as mesh cache, you can animate the frame slider there. Though there is no frame interpolation, so bake your sim with fraction timescale